# Why does Ext flash component concatenate two strings to form this url?

Tags: javascript, string, extjs, extjs3

I found this in the `FlashComponent` source code and was wondering why they broke up the string at `//`. Here's the code:

```
/**
 * Sets the url for installing flash if it doesn't exist. This should be set to a local resource.
  * @static
  * @type String
  */
  Ext.FlashComponent.EXPRESS_INSTALL_URL = 'http:/' + '/swfobject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/swfobject/expressInstall.swf';
```

Comment: I would love to know if there is a reason for this too :) It would partially make sense if it were for `"</sc" + "ript>"`, but that wouldn't matter in an external JS file anyways.

Comment: I wonder if it's how the code is built. Like for some reason, it separates the protocol from the rest of the URL. At the same time, I don't understand why it would split it down the middle of `//`, and why it would concatenate...instead of something like `'{{protocol}}{{rest_url}}';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember it was something to do with satisfying the build tool or a syntax checker  we were using at the time. It has no impact on the code.

Comment: Good enough for me. Thanks for the info.